# Show that $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose $f$ is entire. Let $a\in C $ and $f$ does not take any
> values in the open disc $D_r(a)$. Show that the function $f$ is
> constant.

Please tell me if my solution is correct:

$f $ is entire $\rightarrow h(z) = f(z) - a$ is entire and non zero $\rightarrow g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z) - a}$ is entire.

since $f$ does not take any values in the open disc $D_r(a) \rightarrow |f(z) - a| \geq r \rightarrow |\frac{1}{f(z)-a}| \leq \frac1r \rightarrow |g(z)| \leq \frac1r$

So, $g$ is entire and bounded. So, $g$ is constant (non zero) and hence $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That proof is completely correct.

The same approach is used to proof the [Casorati–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem): If an analytic function omits values from some disk in the neighbourhood of an isolated singularity then that singularity is not essential (i.e. removable or a pole).

Conversely, you *could* use the Casorati–Weierstrass theorem to prove your statement: If $f$ is entire and omits values from an open disk then it cannot have an essential singularity at infinity. It follows that $f$ is a polynomial, and therefore constant.