# Entire function who doesn't take values at a disc is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that it exist a disc $D$ which $f\notin D, \forall z\in 
 \mathbb{C}$, show that $f$ is constant.

---

$\cdot$ Any hints ?

My idea is to consider some function which I can relate it to $f$ (in a way that $f$ is also constant)  and use Liouville's theorem. I was thinking maybe something  $g=1/f$ or $g=f^{-1}$

Comment: first use $g=f-z_0$ to translate the center at zero and then $1/g$ works

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938166/42969